# Coding a series of columns with a numerical condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, case-when

I have a series of columns which are numeric ranged from 0 to 8. I want to make a binominal variable when a row just one time reported 3 or more than coded as  "high" otherwise "low".

```
structure(list(AE_1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), AE_2 = c(0L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AE_3 = c(1L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 0L, 8L, 1L), 
    AE_4 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AE_5 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), AE_6 = c(0L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 1L), AE_7 = c(0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L), AE_8 = c(0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), new_AE = c("low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", 
    "low")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

[image: original data]
I had this code and the outcome is low for all rows.

```
df<-df%>%
     mutate(new_AE=  pmap_chr(select(., starts_with('AE')), ~ 
       case_when(any(c(...) <= 2) ~ "low" , any(c(...) >=3) ~ "high")))
```

while I want something like this : [image: what I want]

Comment: `case_when(any(c(...) >=3) ~ "high", TRUE ~ 'low')` should work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be done esaily be checking max of each row in base R using `pmax`.  Now of course, you won't write 8 col names into `pmax` so do this.

```
df[,9] <- c("low", "high")[ 1 + (do.call(pmax, df[,-9]) >= 3)]

> df
  AE_1 AE_2 AE_3 AE_4 AE_5 AE_6 AE_7 AE_8 new_AE
1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    low
2    1    1    4    1    0    5    1    2   high
3    0    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    low
4    0    1    8    0    1    3    1    2   high
5    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    low
6    2    0    8    0    0    4    2    0   high
7    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    low
```

see that expr inside [] returns true/false as per your desired condition

```
# this returns max of each row
do.call(pmax, df[,-9])
[1] 1 5 2 8 0 8 1

# this checks whether max of each row is 3 or more
do.call(pmax, df[,-9]) >= 3
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

So if you aren't comfortable using this strategy, you may use `replace` instead

```
df$new_AE <- replace(df$new_AE, do.call(pmax, df[,-9]) >= 3, "high")
```

Comment: I like the use of `do.call`, but I'm struggling to understand why you need the `!!`. I get the same result without it, because `+` coerces to integer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `case_when` with the first condition is all TRUE, thus we are only getting the 'low' values.  Here, we don't even need a `case_when` as there are only two categories, and this can be created by converting the logical to numeric index and replace with a vector of labels

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(new_AE = c('low', 'high')[1+ any(c_across(where(is.numeric)) >=3)]) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 9
#   AE_1  AE_2  AE_3  AE_4  AE_5  AE_6  AE_7  AE_8 new_AE
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr> 
#1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0 low   
#2     1     1     4     1     0     5     1     2 high  
#3     0     2     1     1     1     1     1     1 low   
#4     0     1     8     0     1     3     1     2 high  
#5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0 low   
#6     2     0     8     0     0     4     2     0 high  
#7     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     0 low
```

---

Or this may be done more easily with `rowSums` from `base R`

```
df$new_AE <- c("low", "high")[(!!rowSums(df >= 3)) + 1]
df$new_AE
#[1] "low"  "high" "low"  "high" "low"  "high" "low"
```

---

While applying `case_when` have to consider the order of logical statements or make sure to do corrections in the succeeding expressions.  if we test the second of OP's data

```
v1 <- c(1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 5, 1)
any(v1 <= 2)
#[1] TRUE
```

which is the first expression in `case_when`.  As the first one is already executed and found a match, the subsequent expressions are not executed

```
case_when(any(v1 <=2) ~ 'low', any(v1 >=3) ~ 'high')
#[1] "low"
```

By reversing the order, we get "high"

```
case_when( any(v1 >=3) ~ 'high', any(v1 <=2) ~ 'low')
#[1] "high"
```

So, make sure which one is more priority and set the order of those expressions based on that

Comment: fabulous strategy to avoid `case_when` or `ifelse` when we want to have some values instead of `T` or `F` only.  upvoted.

Comment: Bang bang operator is used to convert boolean to numeric. 1 is added to it to return 1 / 2 instead of 0/ 1. These are now used as indices for a vector of two desired values

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
I made a slight modification to my solution as it appears `new_AE` column exists from the beginning and only the values were not right so here is also another solution just in case you would like to use `pmap` in one go. However, you already received some fabulous solutions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(new_AE = pmap(df %>% 
                         select(-9), ~ ifelse(any(c(...) >= 3), "high", "low")))


  AE_1 AE_2 AE_3 AE_4 AE_5 AE_6 AE_7 AE_8 new_AE
1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    low
2    1    1    4    1    0    5    1    2   high
3    0    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    low
4    0    1    8    0    1    3    1    2   high
5    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    low
6    2    0    8    0    0    4    2    0   high
7    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    0    low
```